# Teamcity, wget url and implicit requirements

Tags: teamcity, wget, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to add a library in Teamcity so I can build a nuget package.
Unfortunately the library is on sourceforge so what I want to do is to use wget from a powershell to download the library, unzip it and then build etc...

wget to the .../latest/downloads from sourceforge does not work so I have to get the direct link. That link contains % characters as in %2F %3A which seem to add implicit requirements to the build agent. If I escape them to get past this then the link does not work

Any idea on how to get around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to use curl with -L which is a workaround to the issue but it works

Answer (score -1):

You can escape '%' sign with double '%'. So, '%2F' will be '%%2F'